# Looking for a method to automatically check for file update, and if changes, download to directory on our server

Tags: php, perl

We will be implementing a new template for our web site. The template actually lives on another server.  I would like to schedule a script to run nightly, to check if the remote page has been updated since the last download, and if so, download the file to a directory on our server. 
I can use either perl or php.

Comment: Sounds good. Go for it.

Comment: The traditional Unix route is to use `rsync` ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), [manpage](http://man.cx/rsync)). If you really can't use anything except Perl or PHP, just exec `rsync` from Perl, or something like that.

Comment: Use RSYNC, would be a pain to achieve this with PHP.

Comment: How would rsync work for this? I assume since he says "check if the remote **page** has been updated" this is happening via http.

Comment: Digital Chris is right- it is a page. And in fact, which I did not think to list before, the remote server is an IIS server, whereas we are linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nothing but PHP, you could use something like `similar_text()` (or `levenshtein()` ):

```
if(similar_text( // line breaks for clarity.
    file_get_contents("/path/to/local.tpl"), 
    file_get_contents("http://remote.com/remote.tpl") < 90
 ) {// thus, if the similarity between the two files is less than 90%, 
     file_put_contents("/path/to/local.tpl", "http://remote.com/remote.tpl"); 
 }// download and save the remote template.
```

Or, if you wanted to use `rsync` - just go for `system()` or `exec()` and pass a script as the argument.

to make it run nightly, you just add it to the crontab:

```
crontab -e
```

add:

```
59 23 * * * /path/to/bash-or-php.script
```

Comment: Hope it works -! I'm not too familiar with how well `similar_text` works - and I hear it is slightly prone to error - which is why I wrote in `<90` instead of `<100`